How to execute my script at RunOnce step
I'm trying to download a file using cURL at system startup. My script:
@echo off

echo "Hello, RunOnce script!"
echo "Hello, RunOnce script!" > file.txt
echo %~dp0

curl.exe -L -o image.jpg "https://unsplash.com/photos/rHfsPolwIgk/download?ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MXxzZWFyY2h8MjB8fHRlc3R8ZW58MHx8fHwxNzI2Njk5MTQyfDA&force=true"

echo "Finished"

pause

It is added to the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce registry path. The script works when ran ordinarily from console, but doesn't work correctly when ran as RunOnce script - the output is:
"Hello, RunOnce script!"
C:\Temp\
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (6) Could not resolve host: unsplash.com
"Finished"
Press any key to continue . . .

So it doesn't create the file.txt and cann't download the image, how to fix it?

One possible problem might be the relative path in > file.txt. An absolute file path would be better. The error message curl: (6) Could not resolve host: unsplash.com probably means that the networking / name resolution is not yet ready at the time when RunOnce is executed.

You are using Local Machine (HKLM), which will run the script as system. you can try HKCU, so the script runs when the user logs in, under their account.

Thanks to Bodo and LPChip, I used both of their suggestions - I prefixed paths with %~dp0 and replaced HKLM with HKCU, and it works.
